# Sum of declare time values in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, time, sum, declare

## script

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
   a time := '05:00:00';
   b time := '10:00:00';
BEGIN 
   RAISE NOTICE '%', a;
   PERFORM pg_sleep(5);
   RAISE NOTICE '%', b;
   RAISE NOTICE '%', a + b::time;
END $$;
```

Just i want to add a and b, there result will show 17:00:00 this like.
When i'm writing this "RAISE NOTICE '%', a + b::time;" then raise error
in the following image

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time` datatype represents a precise time  in a day. You can't add two `time`s just as you cannot add two dates. Also, the  hour  part cannot exceed 24

You should rather define it as an interval.

```
knayak=# DO $$
knayak$# DECLARE
knayak$#    a interval := '05:00:00';
knayak$#    b interval := '10:00:00';
knayak$# BEGIN
knayak$#    RAISE NOTICE '%', a;
knayak$#    PERFORM pg_sleep(5);
knayak$#    RAISE NOTICE '%', b;
knayak$#    RAISE NOTICE '%', a + b;
knayak$# END $$;
NOTICE:  05:00:00
NOTICE:  10:00:00
NOTICE:  15:00:00
DO
```

Comment: It's simply working. But into a,b variable I have data that is "time with time zone", so in this case how can I explicit time to the interval? Thanks @Kaushik Nayak

Comment: @Prosenjit : You may have clarified that in the question if that was the case. That calls for a separate question.This answers your original question.

Comment: Yes. I need another question about this.